# Need a complex Xpath using sibling children, ancestors

Tags: xpath, xquery-sql, tree-traversal, siblings

I need to find attribute values based on other values pulled from parent's/grand-parent's sibling's children. I think it's going to take 2 different expressions.

So given the following XML (which is derived from a log file that can be thousands of lines long):

```
<p:log xmlns:p="urn:NamespaceInfo">
 <p:entries>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
     <p:attributes>
       <p:attrib name="Position" value="1B2" />
       <p:attrib name="Something" value="Something_else" />
     </p:attributes>
     <p:msg>
     </p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
     <p:attributes>
       <p:attrib name="Form" value="FormA" />
     </p:attributes>
     <p:msg>
     </p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
     <p:msg>Successful....</p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T12:12:12">
     <p:attributes>
       <p:attrib name="Position" value="1B3" />
       <p:attrib name="Something" value="Something_else" />
     </p:attributes>
     <p:msg>
     </p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
     <p:attributes>
       <p:attrib name="Form" value="FormB" />
     </p:attributes>
     <p:msg>
     </p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
     <p:msg>Processing....</p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
     <p:msg>Error1</p:msg>
   </p:entry>
   <p:entry timestamp="2012-12-31T09:39:25">
    <p:msg>Error1</p:msg>
   </p:entry>
 </p:entries>
     ...
</p:log>
```

- (`<p:attributes>` parent tags can have multiple `<p:attrib>` child tags)
- (`<p:event>` tags can only have one `<p:msg>` tag)

First, I need to grab the value of the `value` attribute that has a corresponding `name` attribute of `Position`, but only if the grand-parent's sibling `p:entry` has a child `p:msg` with the text of `Error1`.  Also, it needs to stay within that section.  For instance, I don't want the first occurrence of the `Position'/'Value` pair because a new `Position`/`Value` pair appears before the `Error1`, even though technically the `p:msg` with the `Error1` is a sibling of both grand-parents.

Next, I need the timestamp attributes' value of the parent of the child whose `Position`/`Value` I just grabbed. So, find the position, then find the timestamp attribute value of the grand-parent `p:entry` tag.

So for this example, I should be able to retrieve the following values only:

`1B3`

`2012-12-31T12:12:12`  (the date/time stamps given are arbitrary values.  This one is different so you know which one I was referencing).

Kind of confusing I know.  I will also need to make sure I grab just one instance because I am using XQuery to get the data out of a database and each expression has to result to a singular value.

I can get to the first timestamp associated with the `p:msg` with `Error1` with the following:  `//p:entry[descendant::p:msg='Error1.'][1]/@timestamp`

but can't seem to get back up the tree to get the other values.

I can get the all of timestamps of the p:events that have p:attrib grand-children with: `//p:entry[descendant::p:attrib[@name=''Position'']]/@timestamp)[1]`

but I can't seem to limit it to just the one that has the 'Error1' following it.  I can't base my selection on position.  I have to base it first on content.

### BONUS QUESTION

How could I do this again on the next instance down the log file? 
(not just the second `Error1` message, the next time down the log file where the `Error1` msg shows up for the next 'parent/sibling' match).  This may be obvious once I get the answer to the questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**:

OK I think I got this. Here's the answer to the first one:

```
//p:msg[text()="Error1"]/../preceding-sibling::p:entry[./*/p:attrib[@name="Position"]][1]/*/p:attrib[@name="Position"]/@value
```

This is working *back* from the `p:msg` tag, which makes it easier to select the first (that's the `[1]` in there) of the preceding parent `p:entry` tags which satisfy the condition that they have a grandchild `p:attrib` with a name `Position`.

Getting the timestamp is just a tad simpler:

```
//p:msg[text()="Error1"]/../preceding-sibling::p:entry[./*/p:attrib[@name="Position"]][1]/@timestamp
```

Try that out and see what you think.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

Normally I don't post half-finished answers, but my guess is that you won't get anything else since this question is so complicated, so here's the xpath for what you describe in the first paragraph:

```
//p:entry[following-sibling::p:entry/p:msg/text()="Error1"]/*/p:attrib[@name="Position"]/@value
```

This will get

> the value of the value attribute that has a corresponding name attribute of Position, but only if the grand-parent's sibling p:entry has a child p:msg with the text of Error1.

However I don't know what you mean when you say "it needs to stay within that section". Can you clarify? This will return both `1B2` and `1B3`.

For the second part of your question, you can get the timestamp for the entries above with this:

```
//p:entry[following-sibling::p:entry/p:msg/text()="Error1" and ./*/p:attrib[@name="Position"]]/@timestamp
```

Again though, this won't do the "section" thing you mentioned. That's a bit more tricky, beyond my (current) knowledge of xpath unfortunately.

Comment: Update: I re-read your question and I think I now understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks shioyama.  This is close to what I need for the one part.  Now I just need to be able to limit it to return one result.  I think I'll create a new xml sample that is more generic but much more clear so that the readers will understand what 'sections' I am referring too.

Comment: So I've been looking at your example and I think I have the general format for grabbing the timestamp but for some reason it's not pulling back any values.  Here's what I have so far:

`//p:entry[following-sibling::p:entry/p:msg/text()="Error1."]/*/p:entry[decendant::p:attrib[@name="Position"]]/@timestamp`

Comment: I think I need to post this to the XQuery crowd.  I just tried to run xpath above in an XQuery script and got an error back saying 'following-sibling' is not supported in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: eh, if following-sibling is not supported then you're not going to get very far!

Comment: Although, I'm not quite where I need to be, I'm really close.  Thanks shioyama for taking the time to look into this.  Once I get the XQuery working (hopefully), maybe I can just get the results I need by creating a temp table in sql and working on the data pulled from the xml.  Still not sure how to limit to the first occurrence though.  Using [1] doesn't work because that is based on the position of nodes in the document, not when the xpath first meets my qualifications.  Oh much fun.

Comment: Hi shioyama, I just saw your comment about following-sibling and I was afraid of that.  I was hoping there might be a work around.

Comment: Thanks for the updates to your answers!  That definitely returns better results.  I do get multiple returns still but I don't think I can get around that with the XML I have to deal with.